# macOS Screen flashing, does anyone know what filters to apple in Console.app for display events?

Tags: macos

My display keeps flashing black for a second. I want to see if there are any events in Console.app.

Does anyone know what filter's to apply in console for display events? or usb events (I'm using a dock sometimes).

Thanks!